# Parallax Scrolling effect with idangerous swiper

Tags: html, css, angular, swiper.js

I'm using idangerous swiper in Angular and I wanted to achieve effect described in https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_parallax.asp.

My HTML file:

```
<div class="container">
  <swiper [config]="config">
    <img class="image" src="../assets/images/item1.jpg">
    <img class="image" src="../assets/images/item2.jpg">
  </swiper>
</div>
```

Config:

```
  config: Object = {
    autoplay: {
      delay: 10000,
      disableOnInteraction: false,
    },
    pagination: {
      el: '.swiper-pagination',
      type: 'bullets',
    },
    effect: "fade",
    speed: 2000,
  };
```

I also added background-attachment attribute as described in tutorial, but it seems it has no effect at all.

```
.image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Is this effect even possible to achieve, or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: What even is 'swiper'...

Comment: Did you have a look at their demo? http://idangero.us/swiper/demos/ Also, it is easier to help if you create a plunkr or stackblitz.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to enable parallax in config.

```
config: Object = {
  autoplay: {
   delay: 10000,
   disableOnInteraction: false,
 },
 pagination: {
   el: '.swiper-pagination',
   type: 'bullets',
 },
 parallax: true,
 speed: 2000,
};
```

Demo is available here: http://idangero.us/swiper/demos/360-parallax.html

Comment: Did you try this? It seems that it has nothing to do with parallax scrolling that I linked.

Comment: yes, you want to achieve vertical effect, so you can make your swiper slider as vertical. you can use: `direction: 'vertical'`